# Antdesign 4 select's placeholder not visible even after assigning undefined to value prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, antd, ant-design-pro

```
<Select  value={undefined} showSearch placeholder="Select Year">
        <Select.Option value={1}>1st Year</Select.Option>
        <Select.Option value={2}>2nd Year</Select.Option>
        <Select.Option value={3}>3rd Year</Select.Option>
        <Select.Option value={4}>4th Year</Select.Option>
        <Select.Option value={5}>5th Year</Select.Option>
        <Select.Option value={6}>6th Year</Select.Option>
</Select>
```

I'm using Ant Design version >4 and using select component like above, still placeholder "select year" is  not visible.
even after removing value prop or adding it, there's no difference.
How to do this???

Comment: Your code example does show the placeholder on the `Select` component when replicated on Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yqlau6?file=index.js

Comment: Check if showSearch is declared or not. Otherwise this could should show placeholder

Answer (score 1):

For me is working with the value undefined, in my case I have the value in an object `data = {...., profession:profession || undefined}` and I'm setting this value as a default because I'm prefilling the values from the data from back, in case that is empty I set the value to undefined, then in the select I add `<Select .... defaultValue={data.profession}/>` and It is showing the placeHolder.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Place holder doesn't show because of showSearch property.

Comment: Please consider your answer as a comment below the question. Or explain or substantiate your answer so people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for some reason the placeholder works just with undefined...
In my case the value of the select was in a state and it overrides the "defaultValue" prop of antd select, so I initialized the state with undefined and the placeholder worked.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItem: undefined
    };
  };

render() {
 const {items} = this.props
 return (
 <Select
   placeholder='Choose an item'  
   value={this.state.selectedItem}
   onChange={this.handleSelect}>
   {items.map(item => (
     <Select.Option key={item._id} value={item.some_value}>{item.name} 
     </Select.Option>
    ))}
 </Select>
)}
```